# Using python to split up a large file into smaller strings with sequence

Tags: python, delimiter

I could do the following in a loop, but was looking for a cleaner way to do this, or better way.

I have a string that may be over 100,000 characters.

example:

somestring,otherstring,mystring,blahstring,etc....

I need to break up the string to multiple strings or a list, each section containing less than 30,000 characters, while only slicing at a delimiter, comma in this example.

Like I said before I wrote up a for loop where I manage it in several lines, but it's messy, and i'm wanting to learn more about python, so thought I would see better ways to handle this here. Thank you for any direction.

Comment: Could you specify what you tried (code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is how I would do it:

```
chunks = []      // used to store the smaller chunks
maxlen = 30000   // maximum chunk size

while True:
    if len(myString) <= maxlen:    
        chunks.append(myString)   // add the last chunk
        break                     // done

    sepIndex = myString.rfind(delim, 0, maxlen)  // find last delimiter < maxlen
    chunks.append(myString[:sepIndex])           // add it to chunks
    myString = myString[sepIndex + 1:]           // remove it and delimiter
```

Operate on a copy of the original string if you need to retain the original string.

P.S. the algorithm is very similar to word wrapping algorithms (split on space under 80 characters, for example) so you could probably search those too.

Comment: This is cleaner than what I was doing. I had a for loop that worked though the string appending the data, but I was doing all the work myself instead of using something like the rfind you have in your example. Thanks, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The python `str` class (strings) includes a method called `split`.  What you will want to do is call `s.split(',')`.  You can replace the comma with your delimiter of choice.  This returns a list of strings. The delimiter will be removed from each of the strings in your list.